# SVN: is there any way to remove the files created after the last revision?

Tags: svn

after doing a `revert -R *` from the root of my project, I revert the state of the files to the last revision. But if I have added new files, they are not removed..

So, is there any way to remove the files created after the last revision?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean `svn update -r{xxx}` where {xxx} is your last revision.

once you commit, it will stay there forever